# What could cause the gradual loss (or change) of power in a CO2 laser over a long period (e.g. a year)?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser

For example, if it were a 10W CW CO2 laser that were used for ~45 minutes per day over a period of a year. Would you expect a slight reduction in power with age?

Does the dissociation of CO2 occur during use? Is this cancelled out by recombination during periods when it is switched off? What about impurities? Are there any other likely causes?

Comment: How much of a loss in power are you experiencing? 5%? 1%? Less? More?

Comment: Dirty optics? If you are using ZnSe, you may need replacements. At visible wavelengths, the index of refraction is relatively low. At 10.6 um, it is much higher. There is a large reflection at each surface. Good anti-reflection coatings are essential. When they get dirty, they don't work well. Ask a company that sells CO2 laser optics for help.

Comment: Here in Australia the accountant in your department would be depreciating the book value of your laser by a third per year to nought over three years. So that's the cause! :) In all seriousness, depending on what the optics are made of, and the environment then yes it happens, mainly through the mechanism stated by @mmesser314: active electromechanical Q switching is common in CO2 lasers and this can lead to slow misalignment. Is yours Q-switched?

Comment: Kyle Kanos: We currently have no way to measure power loss directly, but judging by the change in our results I would VERY roughly estimate a reduction in power of 5%, perhaps slightly more.

mmesser314: Dirty optics is a possibility, thank you.

Rod Vance: It is not Q-switched.

Any other possible reasons?